# Time For iPhone, is there a cmos in iPhone to get time and date?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to work on an app that requires time from the iPhone, but not from the iphone clock where user can modify it, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.  You can only access the clock that a user can change.  You could always write a small web API that you can call to compare the time to the local time and then you can calculate the offset.

Comment: I see , so while the user is not connected , the app won't work right?  there's no other way beside this? was trying to work for an offline apps. Thanks for the feed back.